# limiting number of times a loop runs in php

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that i need to limit to the first 10 items then break out of it.

How would i do that here?

```
foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->screen_name;
    $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
    echo "things";    
}
```

Would appreciate a detailed explanation as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to use foreach, you can add an additional variable to control the number of iterations. For example:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
    if($i==10) break;
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->screen_name;
    $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
    echo "things";  
    $i++;  
}
```

Comment: It should be if($i==10) and not =10.

Comment: Is it able to add something to this that will then allow us to count and output the number of items left in the list that haven't been shown? Like at the bottom of `echo "things";` to have something that says 'and 4 more' ?

Answer (score 15):

You can also use the [LimitIterator](http://docs.php.net/class.limititerator).

e.g.

```
$users = new ArrayIterator(range(1, 100)); // 100 test records
foreach(new LimitIterator($users, 0, 10) as $u) {
  echo $u, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply iterate over `array_slice($butters->users->user, 0, 10)` (the first 10 elements).

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop counter and `break` when you want to exit.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
  $id = $user->id;
  $name = $user->screen_name;
  $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
  echo "things";    
  if (++$i >= 10) {
    break;
  }
}
```

On the 10th iteration the loop will exit at the end.

There are several variations of this and one thing you need to be choose is whether you want to execute the outer loop condition or not. Consider:

```
foreach (read_from_db() as $row) {
  ...  
}
```

If you exit at the top of that loop you will have read 11 rows. If you exit at the bottom it'll be 10. In both cases the loop body has executed 10 times but executing that extra function might be what you want or it might not.

Comment: typo there, should be `($i++ > 10)`

Comment: This will break the `foreach` loop with the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure about wanting to keep the `foreach` loop, add a counter:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->screen_name;
    $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
    echo "things";    

    $count++;
    if ($count == 10)
      break;
}
```

so each time your loop executes, the counter is incremented and when it reaches 10, the loop is broken out of.

Alternatively you may be able to rework the `foreach` loop to be a `for` loop, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can start a counter before your foreach block and check against it in the loop and break if the counter is 10 like so,

```
$count = 1;
foreach ($butters->users->user as $user) {
    if($count == 10)
       break;
    $id = $user->id;
    $name = $user->screen_name;
    $profimg = $user->profile_image_url;
    echo "things";
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like VolkerK's answer, but I don't understand why he is creating a new iterator when most likely you will have an existing array. Just want to share the way I ended up doing it.

```
$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($existingArray);
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

foreach(new LimitIterator($iterator, 0, 10) as $key => $value) {
   // do something
}
```