# how to limit foreach loop to three loops

Tags: php

how to limit this loop ..just thee loops..thanks for helping

```
<?php
    foreach($section['Article'] as $article) :
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php
            if ($article['status'] == 1) {
                echo $article['title'];
            } 
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php
            if($article['status']== 1) {
                echo '&nbsp;'.$html->link('View', '/articles/view/'.$article['id']);
            }
        ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php 
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: where does $section['Article'] come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [limiting number of times a loop runs in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998204/limiting-number-of-times-a-loop-runs-in-php)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Slice the array.

```
foreach(array_slice($section['Article'], 0, 3) as $article ):
```

Comment: +1 This should be the correct answer. It doesn't use if statements, achieves it's goal in one line and is obviously the way foreach is setup to handle this problem. Well even if it's not going to get mark correct, it's the one I will use. I don't want 10 lines of code to tackle a simple problem.

Comment: Cleanest and shortest answer.

Comment: Does this work even if it's out of bounds? Let's say you limit to 5 but the array is only 3 long.

Comment: @MennovanLeeuwen Yes, it does. Just tried.

Answer (score 34):

first, prepare your data

```
$i = 1;
$data = array();
foreach($section['Article'] as $article ) {
  if($article['status']== 1) {
    $article['link'] = $html->link('View', '/articles/view/'.$article['id']);
    $data[] = $article;
    if ($i++ == 3) break;
  }
}
$section['Article'] = $data;
```

then display it

```
<?php foreach($section['Article'] as $article ): ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $article['title'] ?></td>
  <td>&nbsp;<?php echo $article['link']?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 13):

This will help if your array is numerically indexed

```
foreach($section['Article'] as $i => $article ):

    if ($i > 3) break;
```

Otherwise - manually increment the counter:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($section['Article'] as $article ):

    if ($i++ > 3) break;
```

Comment: this is a neat solution

Answer (score 10):

It'd be easier to use a for() loop to do this, but to answer the question:

```
<?
$i = 0;
foreach ($section['Article'] AS $article):
    if ($i == 3) { break; }
?>
...
<?
$i++;
endforeach
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

A foreach loop wouldn't be the best if you need to limit it.  Try using a for loop.

```
<?php

for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
{  
    $article = $section['Article'];


                     ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php if($article['status']== 1){echo $article['title'];}  ?></td>
                        <td><?php  if($article['status']== 1){echo '&nbsp;'.$html->link('View', '/articles/view/'.$article['id']);}?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

This code will make the text loop 3 times.

Answer (score -3):

Awesome one must try this one

```
<?php $count = 0; $pages = get_pages('child_of=1119&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');   foreach($pages as $page) {
$count++;
if ( $count < 50) {  // only process 10 ?>
 <div class="main_post_listing">  <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a><br /></div>
<?php
}  } ?>
```