# Limit amount of lines search echos PHP

Tags: php, search, foreach

I have this code. It let's the user search file.txt & echo's all the results.
I would like to know if there is any way to limit the amount of lines it can echo?
I'm open to any suggestions, even changing the code to a different way of searching.
I've tried putting it in a database, but the file isn't formatted and is 300k+ lines so it's hard to format it so it can go into a database. Thanks.

```
        $lines = file('file.txt');  
        $search = $_POST['Search'];

        $found = false;
        foreach($lines as $line) {
        if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        echo $line . "<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Add a counter and throw a comparison to the counter inside of that if-statement surrounding your `echo`. Or use a `break` with the same comparison.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to limit foreach loop to three loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765879/how-to-limit-foreach-loop-to-three-loops)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a for loop. You may replace

```
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
    $found = true;
    echo $line . "<br>";
}
```

with

```
for($i=0, $j = 0; $i <= $maximumLineNumber; $i++) {
    if(strpos($lines[$i], $search) !== false && $j <= $maximumEchoNumber) {
        $found = true;
        $j += 1;
        echo $lines[$i] . "<br>";
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. This would work if on each iteration `echo` was called, but the `if` statement prevents that. We could go 50 iterations and not of `echo`'ed once.

Comment: I reformatted and corrected a couple of mistakes in the function. It now works as the other solutions, just a bit faster and with less code.

Comment: Again the problem here is that the user wants the limit the number of `echo`'s (which depends on the `if` statement being true), not limit the iterations on a `for` loop. You are counting each iteration as a line being `echo`'ed even if `echo` was not called, so this solution will not work properly.

Comment: Oh ok sorry for having overlooked that; the function is updated and finally working as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('file.txt');  
$search = $_POST['Search'];

$count = 0;
$MAX = 50; // Define the maximum number
$found = false;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    {
        $found = true;
        echo $line . "<br>";
        $count++;
        if ($count == $MAX) { break; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "this code is not very secure" wat.. You should probably elaborate if you're going to make that claim.

Comment: @sjagr I actually had two questions up, and I commented on the wrong one. But it still isn't "secure" since he isn't using `isset()` on the `$_POST` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$max_lines = 30;
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
   if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
        $found = true;
        echo $line . "<br>";
   }
   if($max_lines == $line_num) break;
}
```