# How do I break a foreach loop after it has looped for a set desired number of times instead of the entire array in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, break

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [limiting number of times a loop runs in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998204/limiting-number-of-times-a-loop-runs-in-php)

I am trying to break a foreach loop reading a feed of tweets - after three tweets. Would somebody help with the code I need to supplement to the one i have already.

```
<?php
function getTweets($Username) {
$feedURL = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=" . $username;

$content = file_get_content($feedURL);
$tweets = new SimpleXMLElement ($content);

foreach ($tweets->channel->item as $tweet) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>$tweet->description<br />$tweet->pubDate</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
}
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Add the count parameter to the url

Answer (score 2):

Probably like this.

```
$max_count = 3;
$counter = 0;
foreach ($tweets->channel->item as $tweet) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>$tweet->description<br />$tweet->pubDate</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    if($counter == $max_count){
        break;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: I tried this one, and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

```
foreach ($tweets->channel->item as $tweet) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>$tweet->description<br />$tweet->pubDate</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    if( someCondition )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second answer worked. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I assume items are indexed:

```
foreach ($tweets->channel->item as $i => $tweet) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>$tweet->description<br />$tweet->pubDate</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
    if ($i == 2) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although I thought it looked liked the best solution, this one did not quite work. Unless there is something I did not do right. I would like to cautiously try it again.

Comment: when you var_dump($i); what you get? int(0), int(1) ... or something else? Just use solution by @Bob - that one must work